# How to show logcat logs for more than one app in IntelliJ / Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

On recent IntelliJ versions (specifically IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 Ultimate Edition), it's possible to filter the logs of one Android app, on the logcat panel, by using the "package" property, such as:

```
package:com.example.alpha
```

To see the logs of the other application:

```
package:com.example.beta
```

Is there a way to combine these two log filters with "OR" logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by combining them with "|":

```
package:com.example.alpha | package:com.example.beta
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#logical-operators